# what's the extra space? Is it O(M) or O(M * N)?

Tags: string, stringbuilder

Multiply Strings

Given two numbers represented as strings, return multiplication of the numbers as a string.

Note: The numbers can be arbitrarily large and are non-negative.

This is my code, I know this is not the best solution for this problem, but I have a question about the space complexity, for the res, I know the length will be M + N, but for StringBuilder tmp, the length is M and there are N loops, each loop I create a new StringBuilder whose length is M. So I feel confused, please help me, thank you, guys.

```java
public class Solution {
    // extra space: O(M + N) maybe O(M * N),   354ms
    public String multiply(String num1, String num2) {
        int N = num1.length(), M = num2.length();
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {  // num1
            StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder(M);  // main confusion, the length is M, and N loops
            int carry = 0;
            if (num1.charAt(i) == '0') {  // if the current digit is 0, then continue
                res.append(0);
                continue;
            }
            for (int j = M - 1; j >= 0; j--) {  // num2
                carry += (num1.charAt(i) - '0') * (num2.charAt(j) - '0');
                tmp.append(carry % 10);
                carry /= 10;
            }
            if (carry != 0) tmp.append(carry);  // case: 9 * 9
            tmp = tmp.reverse();
            res = res.append(0);
            // add all the products
            for (int k = res.length() - 1, l = tmp.length() - 1, add = 0; l >= 0 || add > 0; k--, l--) {
                add += ((k >= 0) ? res.charAt(k) - '0' : 0) + ((l >= 0) ? tmp.charAt(l) - '0': 0);
                if (k >= 0) 
                    res.setCharAt(k, (char) ('0' + (add % 10)));
                else
                    res.insert(0, add % 10);
                add /= 10;
            } 
        }
        int r = 0;
        for ( ; r < res.length() - 1 && res.charAt(r) == '0'; r++); // 0 * 0 
        return res.substring(r).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think each time through, you just create one stringbuilder size M, right? So you're constantly using M... and gradually you build up to MN... That's O((M+1)N)... but we typically disregard the single extra M... it's basically O(MN)

Comment: I think the GC would limit the amount of `StringBuilder tmp`s to a constant.